# Firebase v8 - how to access EmailAuthProvider when `firebase.default.auth` is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using Firebase authentication with `AngularFire2` on an Ionic-Angular project. I need to be able to reauthenticate my users when needed, and it seems like the only way to do so is by obtaining the user's credentials, which can only be obtained through `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider`, an object which isn't part of `AngularFire`, but only of `firebase` itself.

I am using firebase v8 for this, on which the `EmailAuthProvider` object should be found in `firebase.default.auth.EmailAuthProvider`. However, I get that `firebase.default.auth` is undefined, and am therefore unable to access `EmailAuthProvider`. The only solution I've found is to revert back to firebase v7, in which the latter can be successfully accessed through `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider`. I cannot upgrade yet to firebase v9 for other compatibility issues, nor want to keep v7 as it gives me loads of high and medium vulnerabilities.

**EDIT**

I obtain the credentials in this manner:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

...

firebase.default.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EmailAuthProvider')
```

My package.json file has `"@angular/fire": "^6.1.5"` and `"firebase": "^8.10.0"`

**TLDR**

In Firebase v8, how to access `EmailAuthProvider`, or more generally, how to reauthenticate a user?

Comment: If you add your code this would be a whole lot more useful, than complaining about the problem. `firebase.default.auth` is probably meant to be called `firebase.auth()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your imports as shown below:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"; 
import "firebase/auth" // <-- make sure you have auth imported
```

Then access EmailAuthProvider like this:

```
firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password)
```